# Conforming Swift Callback With An Objective-C NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cordova, dictionary

Our app uses a Push Plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

One thing the Push Plugin does is swizzle the AppDelegate.m file. Since our AppDelegate file is a .swift, I need to import the core functionality instead.

However, I am running into a problem converting a Swift function to go inside of the NSDictionary Object it expects.

Here is the code I am converting:

```
        void (^safeHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult) = ^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completionHandler(result);
            });
        };

        NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
        [params setObject:safeHandler forKey:@"handler"];

        PushPlugin *pushHandler = [self getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
        pushHandler.handlerObj = params;
```

So the first thing I did was convert the `(^safeHandler)` to Swift as such:

```
            let safeHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> () =
            {
                result in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                {
                    completionHandler(result)
                }
            }
```

Next I need create the `NSMutableDictionary` object that gets set as the `handlerObj` on `pushHandler`.

Putting `safeHandler` directly into the dictionary throws the error

> (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> () does not confirm to AnyObject
>   protocol.

So I tried changing the dictionary type to be `[NSObject : closure]()` by doing the following:

```
            typealias closure = (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void
            var params:Dictionary<String, closure> = Dictionary<String, closure>()
            params["handler"] = safeHandler
```

But when I try to assign the object to the `pushHandler`

```
            pushHandler.handlerObj = params
```

I get the error again

> Cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary' (aka
>   'Dictionary ()>') to type
>   '[NSObject : AnyObject]!'

So back to square one. It seems in Objective-C passing in functions is OK but not so with Swift?

Do you know how I can workaround this issue and get the function into the `[NSObject: AnyObject]` the Objective-C code is expecting?